# drawRect in Master-Detail Application

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawrect

I'm new to Core Graphics (and stackoverflow :) ) and I have created a Master-Detail Application with a `UITableViewController`. Now I would like to add a Core Graphics background to the view to be shown outside of the cells (after the last cell and before the first cell instead of a simple backgroundColor), which I would usually draw within the `drawRect:` method. Of course, since `UITableViewController` is no `UIView` `drawRect:` method is not being called and if I add a `UIView` to the Master View Controller it doesn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the view controller isn't a view but it *manages* a view that you can use.

The table view controller has a `tableView` property to access the table view.

It (the table view) in turn has a `backgroundView` property where you can assign you own custom view that overrides `drawRect:`